# android changing color of image from left to right smoothly

Tags: android, bitmap, spectrum

I want to change the color of an image from left to right like a spectrum and see the change of color as it's changing, here is my code, the problem is that it change from the original image to the final image after a click on buttom, but I don't know how to change it so I can see the change as it's changing.

```
final ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    final Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            for( x = 0; x < mutableBitmap.getWidth() ; x++){
                runOnUiThread (new Thread(new Runnable() { 
                     public void run() {
                         try {
                                        for(int y = 0; y < mutableBitmap.getHeight() ; y++){
                                            int c = mutableBitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                                            mutableBitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(Color.red(c), (200 - Color.green(c)), Color.blue(c)));
                                            Log.d("IMAGE", ""+x);
                                        }   
                                        imgView.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
                                            Thread.sleep(100);
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                             }

                }));
            }
        }


    });
```

Comment: Do you mean like a [color gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_gradient)?

Comment: yes, for example it starts with white and end with green continuously.

Comment: Consider using a `GradientDrawable`, instead of assembling your own bitmap.

Comment: yes but the problem is that I want the color moving from left to right, like swiping a call. actually I should do it for taking a call on swipe on phone, something usual on samsung phones for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on your drawable folder, select New\Drawable resource file. Choose a name for the file and click OK.
After that you can add this code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="135"
    android:centerColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:endColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:type="linear" />
```

You can create new colors from you color.xml and use them. Then in the java code:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.YOURDRAWABLENAME));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but I think you can try this to choose the colors you want:

```
int[] colors = {0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFF0000, 0xFF00FF00}
```

And this to apply them:

```
mutableBitmap.setPixel(x, y, new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, colors);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks but "The method setPixel(int, int, int) in the type Bitmap is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, GradientDrawable)"

Comment: Do you have to do it by code? Because is very easy with xml. You create a new drawable and you apply it to the ImageView, if you're interested and it's what you want, I can show you how

Comment: @BitaMirshafiee

Comment: I was trying doing it by code, I would appreciate if you show me the xml practice